# download url: Web Publish update, released with Visual Studio 2012 RC.

Tags: web, publish

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and working on a MVC 3 project.

I was just reading the:
"Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Hosting Provider using Visual Studio or Visual Web Developer: Introduction - 1 of 12 "

This states ".....install the Web Publish update that was released with Visual Studio 2012 RC."

Where do I download this?

Please note :  I do not want to install VS 2012. I only want to upgrade my VS2010 Ultimate

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the Windows Azure SDK for VS2010: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/downloads/